# How to programmatically gracefully exit from a Micronaut Application

Tags: micronaut

My goal is to programmatically exit my application. I know that this works well with the PicocliRunner, but I can't figure out what is done differently there. Adding the "cli" environment didn't change it.

I added a reproducer [here](https://github.com/alexanderankin/reproduce-close-application-run-does-not-exit).

here is a summary of what i tried:

```java
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS=cli
        ApplicationContext run = Micronaut.run(Application.class, args);
        try {
            EmbeddedServer server = run.getBean(EmbeddedServer.class);
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(server.getURL());
            String s = Mono.from(httpClient.retrieve("/hello")).blockOptional().orElseThrow();
            System.out.println(s); // prints 'world'
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        run.close(); // .stop();, .destroyBean(run);
        System.out.println("closed"); // jvm does not exit
    }

    @io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
    public static class Controller {
        @Get("/hello")
        String get() {
            return "world";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I think the difference between what you are doing and picocli is the Micronaut.run(). The PicocliRunner.execute() execute code then return. Micronaut.run() start the server and never return until the server is shut down. It means that you will never get out of run() until the server is shut down.